# How to add Custom object tab to navigation menu in salesforce app webiste?

Tags: navigation

[image: Marked area is my question...According to admin beginner i created a custom object "Property" and also create a tab associated to property.During tab creation i gave permission to all profiles and make it as "Default On" for all profile. Now when i am opening salesforce in my mobile and login there is no property tab in the navigation menu of salesforce.]
Also how would i know which app currently i am using in salesforce if there are multiple apps.

Comment: Marked area is my question...According to admin beginner Module i created a custom object "Property" and also create a tab associated to property.During tab creation i gave permission to all profiles and make it as "Default On" for all profile. Now when i am opening salesforce in my mobile and login there is no property tab in the navigation menu of salesforce.

Comment: please do not request help asap, it is conssidered rude, and please [edit] your post instead of adding comments.